# Does Flutter FlutterBackgroundService continues running after Vscode debugging ends

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-background

I am currently testing my Flutter app on a physical Android device by running it using Vscode's `Start debugging` command. The Flutter app starts running a `FlutterBackgroundService` using

```dart
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

  await service.configure(
      iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
          autoStart: true,
          onForeground: onStart,
          onBackground: onIosBackground),
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
        onStart: onStart,
        isForegroundMode: true,
        autoStart: true,
      ));

  service.startService();
```

1. If I stop debugging, does the `FlutterBackgroundService` service continues running in the background?
2. If I stop debugging, then start another debugging session using the same `Start debugging` command in Vscode, will there now be 2 such services running?